# Jquery Css SlideToggle

Tags: jquery, css

Looking for help.  I have a ul list with a nested ul for a menu.  Im using slide toggle to toggle the nested item. I have the primary links left aligned ok BUT when i click a primary item to toggle show the subs the main item shift ( i dont what shifting on the primary items) and also the sub li's are left aligned but i just want them to list down.  What am i doing wrong.  Im sure its mostly css related but im stuck?

Here's a link: http://www.k-e-w-l.ca/testing.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the style from `#primary li` is appling to `#subs li` since those `li`s are inside of #primary

```
#subs li{
list-style:none;
float:none;
}
```

should help some.

also you shouldn't use id for subs since there are multiple, use class instead

Answer (score 1):

There are literally dozens of websites describing how to deal with this sort of thing. A few good links:

- [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) - a very good, thorough website with many types of menus
- [Suckerfish dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) - possibly the definitive way to solve this
- [Son of suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

try with giving to child Ul of First parent Ul

```
float:left; and left:0;
```

hope it helps. Well put some code.